# Execution default of goal de-juplo hibernate4 maven-plugin:1.0.4:export failed:

Tags: maven

```
Execution default of goal de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin:1.0.4:export failed: A 
   required class was missing while executing de.juplo:hibernate4-maven- 
   plugin:1.0.4:export:

   /enhanced/OptimizerFactory$StandardOptimizerDescriptor
   [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] realm =    plugin>de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin:1.0.4
   [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy`enter code here`
   [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/.m2/repository/de/juplo/hibernate4-maven- 
   plugin/1.0.4/hibernate4-maven-plugin-1.0.4.jar
```

But the jar is available in the repository

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  `  <plugin>
            <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <hibernateDialect>${h2.db.platform}</hibernateDialect>
                <url>${h2.db.url}</url>
                <username>${h2.db.username}</username>
                <password>${h2.db.password}</password>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <skipEntityClasses/>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>${h2.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.14</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin> ` 
  Add the above err will be wiped out
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).